# Google Chrome Extension Softphone Update via Dev Dashboard Issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, voip

I'm trying to develop a Google Chrome Extension app VoIP softphone. I will be using the Inline Installation feature (https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) and will be publishing on the Chrome Developer Dashboard (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)

My problem is due to the nature of the softphone that has to be always connected, every time I need to publish an updated version of the softphone users will be disconnected, and this will be a big hit on user experience.

Anyone ran into the same issues in publishing a softphone extension app in Google Chrome?

Comment: How frequent are you planning to update the extension?

Comment: @peterdotjs very frequent, maybe at least twice a day?

Comment: That is very frequent. When updating it can take some time to reflect on the client. I haven't seen it consistently update in a certain time period.

Comment: Why are you planning on updating twice a day? Something like once a week would have less impact on users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update may be downloaded at any time, but an extension is only reloaded when the background page goes inactive.

I guess that you're using Web sockets for signaling. Since the connection need to be available at all times, you are probably using a persistent [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). This is enough to prevent a sudden unload. If you use [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), then you need to jump through some hoops to get the page to stay alive even if the Web Socket is not busy all the time ([crbug.com/204573](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=204573)), but also in this case, the extension will not suddenly be reloaded.

If you ***do*** want to reload an extension after an update, add a [`chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable) listener and call [`chrome.runtime.reload`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-reload) when it is convenient (e.g. when the user has unregistered their soft phone, and/or when the user [is idle](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/idle), etc.).

Answer (score -1):

The dashboard provides the ability to ramp up your updates. So only a small percentage of users will be affected at any time under your control.

In addition to the a slow ramp you can do it during off hours to minimize user experience.

This won't solve for disconnections during the update but could minimize the impact.